# Extra byte when creating dynamic string

Tags: c, string

I have written a program to take input and dynamically allocate memory using `realloc()`, however there seems to be an error because if I print the final string char by char I seem to have 2 empty bytes at the end, I am sure this is going to be something silly but I have spent some time trying to discover the cause and have failed so hope to learn something here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int count = 0;
    char *str;
    char tmp;

    str = malloc(sizeof(char));

    while (tmp != '\n') {
        tmp = getchar();

        str = realloc(str, (count + 1) * sizeof(char));

        *(str + count) = tmp;

        count += 1;

    }

    *(str + count) = '\0';

    puts(str);

    // This is just to try and see what was happening
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        printf("str[%d] = %c\n", i, str[i]);

    free(str);
    str = NULL;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Accessing an uninitialized variable invokes undefined behaviour: `while(tmp != '\n')`.

Comment: @Donotalo, thankyou, i get the same result even if i use `do { } while();` and then `tmp` is no longer uninitialized

Comment: Yeah, you want to ponder the code some more, as well.  malloc starts off as size  of one char, then the first realloc is for 1 times the size of one char.

Answer (score 3):

This loop should look at least like

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                ^^^
    printf("str[%d] = %c\n", i, str[i]);
```

Or it would be better to write

```
for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    printf("str[%d] = %c\n", i, str[i]);
```

Or

```
int i = 0;
for ( char *p = str; *p; ++p )
    printf( "str[%d] = %c\n", i++, *p );
```

And change these statements

```
while(tmp != '\n') {
tmp = getchar();
```

to

```
while ( ( tmp = getchar() ) != EOF && tmp != '\n' )
```

Also it would be more safe instead of this statement

```
str = realloc(str, (count + 0x01) * sizeof(char));
```

to write

```
char *p = realloc(str, (count + 0x01) * sizeof(char));
if ( !p ) break;
else str = p;
```

Answer (score 3):

Four things to mention here.

1. `while(tmp != '\n')` is reading uninitialised automatic local variable value without initialization. It  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. `str = realloc(str, (count + 0x01) * sizeof(char));` is very bad, if `realloc()` fails, you'll lose the actual pointer, too. Always use a temporary pointer to hold the return value from `realloc()` and after proper error check, assign it back to the main pointer.
3. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. You don't need to use as a multiplier. It's redundant.
4. The `for` loop condition, should be `i < count` otherwise, you'll run into off-by-one error. `C` uses 0 based indexing.

That said,

- You should always check for the success of the return vale of `realloc()` and family of functions for success before using the returned pointer.
- [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) returns an `int`. You should change the type of `tmp` to `int tmp = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the uninitialized variable access, the two “empty characters” are:

1. a newline, since you check for `\n` before you read and store the next character, and
2. a character in uninitialized memory since you’re incorrectly looping while `i <= count` and not while `i < count`.

Use a `for (;;)` (infinite loop) and check `if (tmp == '\n') { break; }` immediately after `getchar()` to avoid both the uninitialized variable access and trailing newline.